# table creation from CSV file with headers using awk

Tags: csv, awk, tableheader

I have a comma separated CSV file with headers and want to include them in the table

Input:

```
header,word1,word2,word3
supercalifragi,black,white,red
adc,bad,cat,love
```

Output:

```
| header         | word1 | word2 | word3 |
| -------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| supercalifragi | black | white | red   |
| adc            | bad   | cat   | love  |
```

I need to include the headers and I need to take into account the length of the words in the input file so that the finished table formats correctly

Here is the updated code:

```
function pr(){
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "| %-"len[i]+1"s",$i;
    printf "|\n"
}
NR==FNR{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(len[i]<length($i)){
            len[i]=length($i);
            word[i]=$i
        }next 
}{pr()}
FNR==1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        gsub(/./,"-",word[i]);
        $i=word[i]};
    pr() 
}
```

``

Comment: Some thoughts. You don't need to terminate FS, OFS with a semicolon here. In addition, this `, OFS` will print two pipes instead of one (or should): the comma stands for OFS. `printf "\n"` should read `print ""` if you desire a return carriage. It won't print your desired output, though. Finally, `#NR=1`: _no_. That part of your code is executed for all records, so it starts with NR=1 and then is NR=2, NR=3 and so on. You might want to read the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the freedom of rewriting the entire code from scratches. This should work:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    OFS=" | "
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        transientLength[i] = 0
    }
}

{
    if(NR==1) {
    # read headers
        for (i=0; i<NF; i++) {
            headers[i] = $(i+1)
            transientLength[i] = (length($(i+1))>=transientLength[i] ? length($(i+1)) : transientLength[i])
        }
    } else {
        for (i=0; i<NF; i++) {
            fields[NR][i] = $(i+1)
            transientLength[i] = (length($(i+1))>=transientLength[i] ? length($(i+1)) : transientLength[i])
        }
    }
}

END {
    # print header
    for (j in headers) {
        spaceLength = transientLength[j]-length(headers[j])
        for (s=1;s<=spaceLength;s++) {
            spaces = spaces" "
        }
        if (!printable) printable = headers[j] spaces
        else printable = printable OFS headers[j] spaces
        spaces = ""     # garbage collection
    }
    printable = "| "printable" |"
    print printable
    printable = ""      # garbage collection
    # print alignments
    for (j in transientLength) {
        for (i=1;i<=transientLength[j];i++) {
            sep = sep"-"
        }
        if (!printable) printable = sep
        else printable = printable OFS sep
        sep = ""        # garbage collection
    }
    printable = "| "printable" |"
    print printable
    printable = ""      # garbage collection
    # print all rows
    for (f in fields) {
        for (j in fields[f]) {
            spaceLength = transientLength[j]-length(fields[f][j])
            for (s=1;s<=spaceLength;s++) {
                spaces = spaces" "
            }
            if (!printable) printable = fields[f][j] spaces
            else printable = printable OFS fields[f][j] spaces
            spaces = ""     # garbage collection
        }
        printable = "| "printable" |"
        print printable
        printable = ""      # garbage collection
    }

}
```

But please be aware: you need to clean your input file of unnecessary whitespaces. It should read:

```
header,word1,word2,word3
supercalifragi,black,white,red
adc,bad,cat,love
```

Alternatively, you might use `FS=", "`, but that would be actually limited to your example.

Comment: Be sure to check this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931215/table-creation-from-csv-file-with-headers-using-awk/49947613#49947613) answer as well, for more advanced users.

Answer (score 1):

It's not **exactly** the output you asked for but maybe this is all you really need:

```
$ column -t -s, -o' | ' < file | awk '1; NR==1{gsub(/[^|]/,"-"); print}'
header         | word1 | word2 | word3
---------------|-------|-------|------
supercalifragi | black | white | red
adc            | bad   | cat   | love
```

Comment: I guess yes if you are not bothered to add pipes in a second step. I don't remember well how markdown table works: do they need a whitespace near the pipe in `|---|`?

Comment: Never occurred to me that this might have anything to do with markdown, the OP doesn't mention it. I thought they just wanted to see tabular text.

Answer (score 0):

a shorter alternative with double scanning

```
$ awk -F' *, *' 'function pr() 
                 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "| %-"len[i]+1"s",$i; printf "|\n"}

          NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if(len[i]<length($i)) {len[i]=length($i); word[i]=$i} next}

                 {pr()}

           FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/./,"-",word[i]); $i=word[i]}; pr()}'  file{,}

| header         | word1 | word2 | word3 |
| -------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| supercalifragi | black | white | red   |
| adc            | bad   | cat   | love  |
```

Comment: the shorter alternative how would this be implemented using an awk script and not directly from the command line?

Comment: to make a script copy the contents between single quotes to a file and run with `awk -f script.name ... `  If you have specific questions I can answer but you need to put some effort first.

Comment: the problem I encountered when running the file was with file{,}. what is this for.  is this to designate which file i'm using?

Comment: A little bit less readable, but very nice if you want a shorter code.